# How can I combine two rows and avoid duplicating the string entries in the row variables?

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyr

I want to combine two rows in my dataframe into one but avoid duplicating the entries. That is I want to move from this:

```
RowA     RowB
A,B      A,B,C
A        A
```

to this:

```
RowA     RowB     RowC
A,B      A,B,C    A,B,C
A        A        A
```

Using unite from `tidyr`, what I'm actually getting is:

```
RowA     RowB     RowC
A,B      A,B,C    A,B,A,B,C
A        A        A,A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#sample data
df <- read.table(text='colA     colB
A,B      A,B,C
A        A', header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
temp <- df %>% unite(colC, colA, colB, sep=',')
df$colC <- sapply(strsplit(temp$colC ,","), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=","))
```

Output is:

```
  colA  colB  colC
1  A,B A,B,C A,B,C
2    A     A     A
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
df <- read.table(text="RowA     RowB
A,B      A,B,C
A        A", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

myfun <- function(dfrow) {
            paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(dfrow, collapse=","), ","))), collapse=",")
        }

df$RowC <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) myfun(df[i,]))
  # RowA  RowB  RowC
# 1  A,B A,B,C A,B,C
# 2    A     A     A
```